# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken on updating the password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I have a `Ruby On Rails` application. Now, I started getting `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` error while updating `password` in `admin_controller`.
`CSRF` token is present in `layout`.
Earlier it was working, today when I get a warning from `google` to change password, I tried to update the password & got this error.
Below is the request:

```
Started PATCH "/admin/password/change" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-07-25 22:05:38 +0530
Processing by Admin::PasswordsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"osXhNhqJZ9qXeJ4F2BXrJvOTflrG5G3MGPl7yuOa4Y8PoqIXKEVe17bqO5u9nGYG2Bn0Zun2U9mOR4/uxNajsg==", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}
```

I am using `devise-4.3` for authentication.
If tried to update the password 3-4 time, then it works but not each time.

I believe I should refresh the token, `turbolinks` might be creating an issue.

Every other `post/patch` request is working.

`Ruby-2.4.0`, `Rails-5.1.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to Hard reload the page/disable `turbolinks`, so I added the following in `link_to`

```
<%= link_to 'Change Password', change_admin_password_path, data: { turbolinks: false }) %>
```

Now the complete page reload is happening and I am able to update the password.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the controller that’s generating the error, and paste following line of code above all the defined functions:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create
```

OR

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

save it then restart the server!
Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: I have both in my `admins_controller`